# Nginx fastcgi cache not working for session_start

Tags: php, nginx

I'am following the tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-fastcgi-caching-with-nginx-on-your-vps) to setup fastcgi cache for php.
It works and preform well.

```
<?php
    echo time();  // the output can be cached
?>
```

But once i add the code `session_start()`, the caching function is not working now.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo time();  // cache fail
?>
```

Can someone help? I want the php output cached with the use of session.

Comment: That might be causing a set-cookie header to be attached the response. NGINX won't cache responses with set-cookie by default